# can this be rewritten with JOIN instead nested query?

Tags: sql

im new in sql and i that in general is better to avoid subquerys, so i want to know how can i rewrite this with joins...

```
SELECT ccn.*
FROM table1 AS  ccn 
WHERE ccn.col1 = '11'
AND ccn.col2  not in (SELECT table2.col4
                      FROM  table2)
```

regards

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing this using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ccn.*
FROM table1 ccn 
WHERE ccn.col1 = '11' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.col4 = ccn.col2
                 );
```

This usually has the best performance -- and probably treats `NULL` values as you want them to be treated.

A `LEFT JOIN` with filtering is pretty similar in performance:

```
SELECT ccn.*
FROM table1 ccn LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.col4 = ccn.col2
WHERE ccn.col1 = '11' AND t2.col4 IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks....but seems no method works...including mine:

Comment: thanks....but seems no method works...including mine:

ccn table.col2=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
t2 table.col4=(3,4,5,6)

i expect recover the rows from ccn where col2 =1 and 2
but i obtain 0 rows....missing some concept here....¿?

Comment: @oso_togari . . . I'm a bit lost.  These queries are (essentially) replacements for the `NOT IN`, so they answer your question.  If you have a *different* question, ask it as a *new* question.